# store emails in textfile? php

Tags: php, file, variables

This spinet of code renders a users email when a user enters a page of my site:
.
.

```
$email=$userprofile->email;
```

.
.
you can echo it like this:

```
<?php echo $email;?>
```

but how would you store it in a text file with one email per line? thanks

Answer (score 2):

`file_put_contents("name_of_file.txt", preg_replace("/\r|\n/"," ", $email)."\n");`

Learn to use the [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) docs. They are [excellent](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Comment: Might want to add a `\n` after the `$email` variable so the next one is written on a new line.

Comment: @FreekOne yeah, i also added a replacement to remove newlines from the source `$email` thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `trim($email)."\n"` be enough though ?

Comment: @freekOne not if the `email\nhas\several\nnewlines\n\in it\nalready`

Comment: @Byron not that that can happen (as far as i am aware) in a valid email, still... better to be safe than sorry ;)

Comment: Ah, true, but since it's being assigned by `$email=$userprofile->email` I don't think that is the case, and `preg_replace()` is kind of overkill. Good solution nevertheless.

Comment: I would rather use something like this: `strtr($mytext, array("\n"=>'', "\r"=>''));` instead of a regexp.. But probably the best way would be to just validate the e-mail address somewhere else :)